# jetty root context not working as expected

Tags: jetty, jetty-8

My jetty context xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  **<Set name="contextPath">/</Set>**
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/../core.war</Set>
</Configure>
```

My rail server talks to jetty. However, the I get some "server errors"

But when I change the contextPath as follows, then it works:

```
  **<Set name="contextPath">/foo</Set>**
```

Could you please tell me why root context is not working?

Answer (score 1):

try naming it root.xml and your war file root.war

Comment: just a common naming convention, if it is foo.war then it defaults to foo context with servlets inside matching / and servlet/...and if you use root.war then that implies to the container it should serve root content, otherwise you get a list of the deployed webapps

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications (need to sort out why I don't see this in the 9 docs atm)

Comment: I only have the high level view of error which is "accessing http://localhost:8080/resources gives 404 - Not found error" but if I add /foo to contextPath and access http://localhost:8080/foo/resources  then everything works as expected. Jetty Logs do not seem to indicate any error